# Reduce size of a SQLite database

Tags: database, sqlite

I created a SQLite database from the Yelp datasets for a client. The resulting .db file is 8.2GB in size, but their server is optimized for smaller databases -- 1GB or smaller, ideally ~100MB.

How on Earth do I shrink down my 8.2GB database to that tiny size?

If anyone has any thoughts, I would appreciate them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you've deleted data from the database and want to reclaim the space, use [VACUUM](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html). Other than that, not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: There will be no broken relationships if you delete *all* data. However, I doubt that the result is what you want …

Comment: I shouldn't have said anything about deleting rows, since that muddled the question. The essential question is how I should go about shrinking an 8.2 GB SQLite database to 1GB or smaller.